SLURM re-queue running jobs
when I setup jobs to run for days, they start running but after 1-2 days are re-queued and restart running from zero in a different node. Is there any way to avoid this, squeue-setup/code/option, what starts must finish ...

Any clue in the job output file? A time limit reached? A node that fails?

Hi damienfrancois, the node doesn't fail as also the time limit is not reached. I can not see something in the slurm logs (job output file). For me seems like that the queue stop the job in the way to give space to run other jobs for some time, but then when is going back to continue running the long job insteatd to continue it, it restarts ... this is just a fealing

offhand the two reasons that might happen are a) the node failed, and your job was automatically requeued, or b) the slurm cluster is configured to allow pre-empting by higher-priority work and your job got pre-empted.  If it's b), you should ask the cluster admins how they expect you to submit your work (possibly with --exclusive=user).  You should also investigate checkpointing if possible, so you lose less work if your job is killed

Thanks! I see that the conf. file has PreemptType=preempt/partition_prio and now was changed to PreemptType=preempt/none
